# Remove html extension from urls return error 404 in yii

Tags: yii, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

My current user's page urls:

http://mydomain.com/user/OXaEfrta.html

In order to achieve these urls, I set this line in urlManager:

```
'user/<aid:\w+>'=>array('/Users/profile/view', 'urlSuffix'=>'.html')
```

When I attempt to remove `'urlSuffix'=>'.html'`, they turn out with error 404.

How would I deal with this issue?

//Edit

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: what about .htaccess?

Comment: I've just edited this. Thanks for reminding me.